# Backup taking longer time than usual in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have rebuilt huge table. After it my database is extended 1.3 TB to 1.5 TB. I don't shrink free space in data file because of it's impact fragmentation of index. After rebuilding process my daily full backup taking longer than usual. Before rebuilding backup take 1 hour but after rebuilding taking 4 hour.

What is the reason of ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: What's about the backup size? Is it increased as well?

Comment: Next time backup runs look at the top waits, is there any other resource intensive process which runs at that time ?

Comment: @Shanky, we found processes at that time, after change it, all are okay. But backup was worked 1 hour with this process before rebuilding.

Comment: @natiqrzazade What was the process ?

Comment: @shanky it's our own solution for migration data production to archive.